# What kind of object do I have?

Tags: jquery

I have done much searching but have come up empty. I thought I could get a specific child from `.children()` by doing something like:

```
.children("span.some-class a img");
```

and indeed I can see the object when I output it to the console. However, I can't do something like this:

```
.children("span.some-class a img").attr("src");
```

It seems to be undefined. So I have a couple of questions: 1) What kind of object is `.children("span.some-class a img");` and 2) How do I get the URL that I am after?

```
<li>
    <span class="some-class">
        <a href="#"><img src="img/photo.png" alt=""></a>
    </span>
    <span class="some-class-1">
        <a href="#">Item</a>
        <span>Quantity: 400</span>
    </span>
    <span class="some-class-2">
        <a id="foo" href="#"><i class="yet-another-class"></i></a>
    </span>
</li>
```

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Cheers in advance!

Comment: Try `.find("span.some-class a img");`

Comment: `children()` only looks at child elements. Given your selector you're going multiple levels down the DOM, so `find()` is what you need.

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden All jQuery DOM traversal methods return an object.

Comment: Can you show your HTML structure, and which element you're calling `.children()` on?

Comment: Edited the original post adding the HTML. You can see that I am attempting to get the children of the `<li>` element. My thinking is rather than finding or traversing, I could get them directly as it most like is faster. Further, I know that there are always only going to be 3 direct `<span>` descendants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) It's a jQuery object that represents the collection of all children matching the selector. It could be an empty collection; you can use `.length` to find out how many elements are matched.

```
.children("span.some-class a img").length
```

2) `.attr()` returns the value of the attribute from the first element of the collection. It will return `undefined` in two cases: if the collection is empty (`.length` above returns `0`) or the attribute has never been set on the element.

Answer (score 1):

if you only work with JQuery like you did you will get an `Array<JQuery>` for your selector.

perhaps my solution helps you to understand how it works if you break down to `HTMLElement`'s and it in several steps.

HTML:

```
<!-- ... -->
<span class="some-class">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="img1.png" />
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="img3.png" />
  </a>
</span>

<span class="some-class">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="img2.png" />
  </a>
</span>
<!-- ... -->
```

Typescript (also works in js if you remove the type definitions `: HTMLElement`)

```
// ...
$('span.some-class').find('a').each((i, linkElement: HTMLElement) => {
  $(linkElement).find('img').each((i, imgElement: HTMLElement) => {
    console.log($(imgElement).attr('src'));
  });
});
// ...
```